# I need flutter app continue execution when screen is locked or minimized

Tags: flutter, dart

We created an application with Flutter which allows to check if the position of the phone is vertical, once the phone is horizontal it launches an audible alert and a message appears on the screen, it works perfectly when the application is open .

We wish that once the application launch even if the phone is locked or the application is minimized, the application continues and check if the position of the phone is still vertical and still launch the message on the screen + the audible alert, do you have any idea if this is possible with Flutter? we did not find any track.

Thank you in advance for your answers, it will help us move forward a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with [background processes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)